# Which permission to use for accessing files and folders of other apps in Android/media folder in Android 11?

Tags: java, android, android-11

I want to request permission to access files (but NOT All Files Access) in Android 11. I am able to request permission for Photos and Media but not files. If I use MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, playstore rejects app.
Can anybody help?

Comment: its obivio that playstore rejects the app its written in the android 11 behavorial changes . only if you had read it  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access-google-play

Comment: if you want to upload specific file you can set file mime type when accesing it

Answer (score 0):

You can [Grant access to a directory's contents](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory)

Steps:

- check if user has grant permission for a folder

```
    private fun hasPermission() = run {
        try {  
            val uri = PreferenceUtil.getString(PreferenceKey.TREE_URI).toUri()
            DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(requireContext(), uri)?.canWrite()  
        } catch (e:Exception) {  
            false  
        }
    }
```

Java

```
    private boolean hasPermission() {
        try {
            SharedPreferences preferences = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            String treeUri = preferences.getString(PreferenceKey.TREE_URI, "");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(treeUri);
            return DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri).canWrite();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

- request access folder permission

```
    private val SELECT_TREE_FOLDER: Int = 100
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
    startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_TREE_FOLDER)
```

- After user choose a folder, grant read & write permission and store
  treeUri to SharePreference

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return
        if (requestCode == SELECT_TREE_FOLDER) {
            val treeUri = data?.data ?: return
            if (DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(requireContext(), treeUri)?.canWrite() == true) {
                var takeFlags = data.flags
                takeFlags =
                    takeFlags and (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                requireContext().contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, takeFlags)
                PreferenceUtil[PreferenceKey.TREE_URI] = treeUri.toString()
            }
        }
    }
```

- After user grant permission, you can [read content](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open) of all file in that folder.

Comment: You can see java version in android docs. Only method check access permission i write in kotlin. I will update a java version.